# Class 'ActionImageListFragmentToImageDetailsFragment' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun getActionId()

Tags: kotlin

I want to send data between fragments using arguments but I get this error

```
e: C:\Users\aziz\StudioProjects\Imageswithbase\app\build\generated\source\navigation-args\debug\com\example\images\ui\ImageListFragmentDirections.kt: (10, 16): Class 'ActionImageListFragmentToImageDetailsFragment' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun getActionId(): Int defined in androidx.navigation.NavDirections
```

when use click card view it suppose to open ImageDetailsFragment and arguments send author and downloadurl to ImageDetailsFragment

ImageGridAdpter

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val images = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(images)

        holder.card.setOnClickListener {
            val action = ImageListFragmentDirections.actionImageListFragmentToImageDetailsFragment(
                 author = images.author, downloadUrl = images.download_url
            )
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
    }
```

ImageDetailsFragment

```
    private lateinit var author:String
    private lateinit var download_url:String
    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        arguments?.let {
            author = it.getString("author").toString()
            download_url = it.getString("download_url").toString()
        }
    }
```

nag_graph

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/imageListFragment"
        android:name="com.example.images.ui.ImageListFragment"
        android:label="Images"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_image_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_imageListFragment_to_imageDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/imageDetailsFragment" >

            <argument
                android:name="author"
                app:argType="string" />
            <argument
                android:name="download_url"
                app:argType="string" />

        </action>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/imageDetailsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.images.ui.ImageDetailsFragment"
        android:label="Image"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_image_details" />
```